# Meaning of "They are so used to me"

Tags: meaning

Can you tell me meaning of this:

"They are so used to me that they know my schedule."

Which means that they know him or something else?

Comment: Reference: [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/use?q=be+used+to#use__16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Used to" in this context is idiomatic for "familiar with" or "accustomed to".

> They are so familiar with me that they know my schedule.

It could also be used in the following scenarios:

> I am so used to forgetting my glasses, I keep a spare pair at work.

or

> He was so used to losing his chess games that he stopped being optimistic.